# Odroid N2+ board program does not open

Tags: android, android-studio, odroid

I am writing simple test app for Android things. I am using Odroid N2+ board.
I have not made any changes in the code yet when I download app to Odroid Board from Android Studio, the app crashes/closes itself.

Firstly I set minimum SDK to 28 (Android Pie 9.0)and targetSDK and compileSDK to 31. Also from sdk 31 , I set

```
       android:exported="true"/"false"
```

When it did not work, I set compileSDK and targetSDK to 28 and one more change was

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
```

Besides there, there is no changes. Why is it not working ?

Comment: If it crash/stop there is an stack trace, see: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/295004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Logcat error said "**You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity**". So I changed the theme as below

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Its working so far